# What is ipairs in lua stands for?

Tags: lua

I know that `pairs` in lua iterates through pairs according to hash key, which means no specific order, and `ipairs` iterates from 1 until an absent key, which will not iterate through all pairs if there is a gap.

My question is, what is the `i` in `ipairs` stands for? I have a hard time thinking up a mnemonic explanation.

Some of my guesses are:

1. Incremental-key-order
2. In-order-iteration
3. Just because it behaves
   like a for loop, which use `i` a lot

Comment: this is not a discussion board. as the reference manual does not say anything about it, no one but the guy who named that function like that can give you a definite answer to your question. anybody else can just guess like you.

Comment: I'm just curious about whether there is a way to memorize it or not.

Comment: A good mnemonic would be **Integer Pairs**, as it gets the key value **pairs** of each of the **integer** keys.

Comment: Probably, this is indeed **integer**, but nobody knows for sure (as the manual keeps silent on that).  What if this is the first letter of the last name of "Roberto Ierusalimschy" ? :-)

Comment: I agree with [ATaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7170955/ataco).  From the [Lua Unofficial FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.10) `pairs(t)` gives a general iterator over **all** the keys and values in a table, numerical or not, in no particular order; `ipairs(t)` goes over the **array** part, in order.